# Ecto Elixir: Sum values in preloaded association

Tags: mysql, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a database which has different songs that can have multiple requests and each request can in part have multiple votes.

I'm trying to build a query that gets all of the info for a request (song information and votes made by users) but I just want to select the important information I need.

I currently have it set up like this

```
def get_requests_in_zone(zone_id, max_played) do
query = from request in Request,
  left_join: song in assoc(request, :song),
  where: request.zone_id == ^zone_id and request.times_played <= ^max_played,
  select: request,
  preload: [song: song],
  order_by:  [asc: request.times_played, desc: request.inserted_at]
Repo.all(query)
 end

def  calculate_rating(request_id)do
query = from votes in Vote,
  where: votes.request_id == ^request_id,
  select: sum(votes.rating)

Repo.one(query)
end

def get_requests_in_zone_with_votes(zone_id,max_played) do
Enum.map(get_requests_in_zone(zone_id,max_played),
  fn(x) ->
    %{title: x.song.title, url: x.song.url, thumbnail: x.song.thumbnail, rating: calculate_rating(x.id)} end)
end
```

But that makes multiple queries to calculate the rating for each request. I tried building a single query, it was something akin to:

```
def get_requests_in_zone(zone_id, max_played) do
query = from song in Song,
  left_join: request in assoc(song, :requests),
  join: votes in assoc(request, :votes), 
where: request.zone_id == ^zone_id and request.times_played <= ^max_played,
  select: %{title: song.title, url: song.url, thumbnail: song.thumbnail, rating: sum(votes.rating)},
  preload: [requests: {request, votes: votes}],
  order_by:  [asc: request.times_played, desc: request.inserted_at]
Repo.all(query)
end
```

But it didn't work... Giving out this error message

** (Ecto.QueryError) field `.Song.request` in preload is not an association in query:

So I decided to add the complete song in the select by changing the select line to

```
  select: %{song: song, rating: sum(votes.rating)},
```

And it just said 
     ERROR 42803 (grouping_error): column "s0.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

How could I build a query that retrieves the requests and returns a struct similar to the one used in get_requests_in_zone_with_votes?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: "But it didn't work..." did it cause a compile error? a runtime error? or gave the wrong result?

Comment: I just updated the question. 
But it just said: ERROR 42803 (grouping_error): column "s0.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate

Comment: Try to add `group_by: request.id` to the `query`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. 
It now says the same for another column.
Specifically: ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42803 (grouping_error): column "v2.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the sum in a subquery, and join to it from the main query:

```
q1 = from votes in Vote,
     group_by: votes.request_id,
     select: %{request_id: votes.request_id, total_rating: sum(votes.rating)}

q2 = from request in Request,
     left_join: song in assoc(request, :song),
     left_join: rating in subquery(q2), on: request.id == rating.request_id,
     where: request.zone_id == ^zone_id and request.times_played <= ^max_played,
     select: %{title: song.title, url: song.url, thumbnail: song.thumbnail, rating: rating.total_rating},
     order_by:  [asc: request.times_played, desc: request.inserted_at]
```